# chi square for trend - SPSS

Tags: spss, chi-squared-test, trend

I have followed fourth-year university students for ten years, recording their attitudes to a particular lecture.
The outcome is binary (good-bad). I have 10 rows and 2 columns, meaning year and attitude, respectively. The number of responses vary from 60 to 90 depending on the year.  **How should I perform an analysis to look for a significant change in their attitudes?**  Can I use chi-square for trend using Crosstabs with each year in the rows and good-bad in the columns, looking at linear-by-linear association for a possible significant change in their attitudes?

I understand this is perhaps a simple question, but being a novice I would very much appreciate your explanations nonetheless!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "chi-square for trend" and "linear-by-linear association"?  What exactly are these procedures?

Comment: I have 10 rows and 2 columns, meaning year and attitude, respectively. How should I perform an analysis to look for a significant change in their attitudes?

Comment: That's a good way to ask your question (+1).  I have taken the liberty of copying your comment into the post, because not everybody will read the comments.